MSBuild ignores Target.Inputs and Target.Outputs and doesn't do up-to-date-check
I created razor pages web app with Visual Studio 2022 (MSBuild version 17?) and added the following to csproj file:
<Target Name="BuildCss" BeforeTargets="Build"
        Inputs="Pages/pages.css"
        Outputs="wwwroot/css/styles.css">
    <Copy SourceFiles="Pages/pages.css" DestinationFiles="wwwroot/css/styles.css" />
</Target>

I will transform Pages/pages.css file before copying it to wwwwroot/css, but for now to test MSBuild's fast up-to-date-check feature, I just copy the file.
Now, the first time I ran the build, file copy succeeded as expected, but after that it doesn't work, even if I edit pages.css file or even delete styles.css file. In outputs window I see
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

What am I doing wrong here?

I did a quick test and can reproduce the same issue in VS2022. However, from looking at this doc DisableFastUpToDateCheck, it says

The Visual Studio build manager uses a process called FastUpToDateCheck to determine whether a project must be rebuilt to be up to date. This process is faster than using MSBuild to determine this. Setting the DisableFastUpToDateCheck property to true lets you bypass the Visual Studio build manager and force it to use MSBuild to determine whether the project is up to date.

You can set the property DisableFastUpToDateCheck to true in .csproj file to disable FastUpToDateCheck for Visual Studio build manager:
<PropertyGroup>
    <DisableFastUpToDateCheck>True</DisableFastUpToDateCheck>
</PropertyGroup>


As @Dou Xu-MSFT's answer shows, both MSBuild and Visual Studio have their own up-to-date-checks. My understanding is that, in case of Visual Studio, it is called fast up-to-date-check (FUTDC). I couldn't find related documentation on Microsoft Learn, but on GitHub there's a repository: https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/blob/main/docs/up-to-date-check.md.
So, while I can disable FUTDC as in the @Dou Xu-MSFT's answer, it's not desirable, because in that case, as my experiment showed, the build process was running all the time.
I found a better way to deal with the issue:
<ItemGroup>
  <UpToDateCheckInput Include="Pages/pages.css" Set="Css" />
  <UpToDateCheckOutput Include="wwwroot/css/styles.css" Set="Css" />
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="CompileCss" BeforeTargets="Compile">
  <Copy SourceFiles="Pages/pages.css" DestinationFiles="wwwroot/css/styles.css" />
</Target>

UpToDateCheckInput, UpToDateCheckOutput properties seem to be specific to Visual Studio (not for MSBuild).
Also, BeforeTargets="Build" was issuing warning message in the output window

The project does not appear up-to-date after a successful build: Input UpToDateCheckInput item '...\wwwroot\css\styles.css' is newer than earliest output '...\obj\Debug\net9.0\staticwebassets.build.json'

Warning message is gone when I used BeforeTargets="Compile".

Glad to hear you have found the solution of the issue. Thanks for sharing the document Up-to-date Check
